# Error 400 while using Dropbox chooser API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to use Dropbox chooser using Javascript. Google chrome browser used. 
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser

I have registered the app as asked and given the redirect URI also. 
And I have used the app key in my application.

However when I invoke the choose window using the code snippet they have provided, it ends up with 400 error.

I have attached a reference screenshot herewith. 
[Error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ3ky.png)

Kindly advise on this.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Eroor-400-when-using-the-Dropbox-choose-API/m-p/302473 ]

Comment: This issue is solved. I am able to select a document from Dropbox using Dropbox chooser API https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser. However once I select, I am able to get the metadata of the document like id, URL etc. I need to read the content of this file. Any leads pls?.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Eroor-400-when-using-the-Dropbox-choose-API/m-p/304452/highlight/true#M18373 ]